# enable Chrome flags from the command line

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to enable a flag (enable-token-binding) while launching chrome. 
I can do that using chrome://flags page. but for running tests I need to do it from command line.

I tried

chrome --enable-features=token-binding

chrome --enable-token-binding

None of them worked.

Comment: Try `--flag-switches-begin --enable-features=token-binding --flag-switches-end`

Comment: @wOxx doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then. Try reporting on https://crbug.com

Answer (score 9):

1. go to chrome://version
2. Find the command line arguments:

Command Line    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --enable-audio-service-sandbox **--flag-switches-begin --enable-features=CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure,SameSiteByDefaultCookies --flag-switches-end --enable-audio-service-sandbox**

Run the above command with all the arguments and your chrome instance would have all the settings preset.

Comment: This no longer works.  Any idea why?  Has chrome deprecated this feature?

Comment: @Matthew looks like chrome has disabled it completely.

Comment:  @#$%^&*(*&^%$ 
haha, thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

Try `--flag-switches-begin --enable-token-binding --flag-switches-end`.

The patter is `--flag-switches` start and ends capping the flags. Then the names of the flags provided as the parameters within with `--` prefixed to them.

Answer (score 1):

Token Binding was removed in Chrome release 70

see https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5097603234529280

mayankSinha's answer works for the flags he mentions. Note the changed naming convention though: "lower case split by -" convention gets changed to CamelCase.

i.e. same-site-by-default-cookies (as shown in chrome://flags) becomes SameSiteByDefaultCookies